# [iPhone][UITableView]How to know when a group complete replace other (by scroll)?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Please refer to bellow image to get detail:
[image]

I think, UITableView has some events occur when scrolling em when a group complete replace other, but I don't know :(

Comment: You can access the content offset via the UITableView's contentOffset property (as it subclasses UIScrollView), but then you would have to calculate it yourself.

BTW hi kennytm ;).

Comment: @chpwn: you're so funny :)
@chpwn: I need to know a event which occur when group B is scroll up and replace group A.

Comment: +1 for the illustration. That really helps make the question clear. Wish more people took the time to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get drawing rectangle for each section using `-rectForSection` method (see "Accessing Drawing Areas of the Table View" part in UITableView docs). Then in your UITableViewDelegate implementation you can track scrolling events in table view, e.g. in `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method you can compare current `contentsOffset` and origin point of the rectangle for each section to determine which section is active at the moment.